# Redirection when CORS credentials : true

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I wrote a basic authentication code for logging a user in. The code basically generates a JWT token with a given set of params and registers a cookie onto the requesting client.

Now, I want to redirect the user to the last route.

I believe this is done using
`res.redirect('back')`

Yes, I am using `express` and `React` with `react-router-dom`

Here is the login code:

```js
const login = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body

    const user = await Users.findOne({
        email
    })

    if (user && user.id) {
        // user was found
        // check the password
        const isValidPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)
        if (isValidPassword) {
            // generate a JWT token
            const authToken = jwt.sign({
                id: user.id,
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                created_at: user.created_at
            }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
            })

            // log him in
            // const response = {
            //     id: user.id,
            //     email: user.email,
            //     name: user.name,
            //     created_at: user.created_at
            // }
            res.cookie(COOKIE_TOKEN, authToken, {
                maxAge: +process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
                httpOnly: true
            })/*.send(response)*/.redirect('back')
        }
        else {
            res.status(401).send("Incorrect password")
        }
    }
    else {
        res.status(404).send({
            status: "Failed",
            reason: "Incorrect credentials or the user doesn't exist"
        })
    }
}
```

Now, the redirect call shows a CORS error on my React app.

Also note, I have used `credentials: true` for my `cors` configuration.

Here is the `cors` part of the code:

```js
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
}))
```

The `credentials : true` is required to establish server-side cookies and that is a must for my application.

Please give me an explanation as to why my redirect is not working and what are the changes required.

P.S. The `login` route is a POST request

Comment: Did you get the same CORS error if you redirect with `'http://localhost:3000'` ?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you please explain? @ShueiYang

Comment: Since you said you get this error when you try to redirect back to the last login route, i want to know if you try to redirect back to the main page  with `.redirect('http://localhost:3000')` you got the same issue.

Comment: Yeah i did get the same issue. I can submit the error log too if you want that

Comment: can you add to your Cors setting a line for method like this just in case : `methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work @ShueiYang

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251270/discussion-between-shueiyang-and-arjis-chakraborty).